# MSMQ How best to handle classes when using binary encoding

Tags: class, binary, msmq, formatter

I'm new here, so please be gentle.

This question revolves around VB.net / VS2010 / MSMQ 4.0

I'm developing an application that has MSMQ at its heart.  There are (currently) 3 separate VB solutions each of which send and receive message to a queue.

I tried using the XMLMessageFormatter and ran into problems with that, plus this is a high performance, time critical app and I understand that XMLMessaegFormatter has a high overhead, so I've switched over to using BinaryMessageFormatter for the messages.

I've established a class (clsTMessage) which provides the structure for the message data and resides in its own .vb file attached to the solution.  I realize that the downside of using Binaryformatter is that the exact same class (down to version and all) has to encode and decode the messages and indeed I'm seeing that problem.

So I figured, no problem, I'd just copy clsTmessage.vb to each solution, but that doesn't quite do the trick as the messages encodes with the namespace of the host assemby and therefore the next solution to pick up the message is technically looking for a different class to decode it.

In this example, for instance, you can see that TelemanusWorkbench Version 1.0.0.0 encoded the message using TelemanusWorkbench.clsTMessage.

```
00 01 00 00 00 FF FF FF .....ÿÿÿ
FF 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 ÿ.......
00 0C 02 00 00 00 49 54 ......IT
65 6C 65 6D 61 6E 75 73 elemanus  
57 6F 72 6B 62 65 6E 63 Workbenc
68 2C 20 56 65 72 73 69 h, Versi
6F 6E 3D 31 2E 30 2E 30 on=1.0.0
2E 30 2C 20 43 75 6C 74 .0, Cult
75 72 65 3D 6E 65 75 74 ure=neut
72 61 6C 2C 20 50 75 62 ral, Pub
6C 69 63 4B 65 79 54 6F licKeyTo
6B 65 6E 3D 6E 75 6C 6C ken=null
05 01 00 00 00 1E 54 65 ......Te
6C 65 6D 61 6E 75 73 57 lemanusW
6F 72 6B 62 65 6E 63 68 orkbench
2E 63 6C 73 54 4D 65 73 .clsTMes
73 61 67 65 09 00 00 00 sage....
0E 6E 65 77 4D 65 73 73 .newMess
61 67 65 54 79 70 65 12 ageType.
6E 65 77 50 72 6F 74 6F newProto
63 6F 6C 56 65 72 73 69 colVersi
6F 6E 0D 6E 65 77 49 64 on.newId
65 6E 74 69 66 69 65 72 entifier
0B 6E 65 77 53 6F 75 72 .newSour
63 65 49 50 0D 6E 65 77 ceIP.new
53 6F 75 72 63 65 50 6F SourcePo
72 74 10 6E 65 77 44 65 rt.newDe
73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 6F stinatio
6E 49 50 12 6E 65 77 44 nIP.newD
65 73 74 69 6E 61 74 69 estinati
6F 6E 50 6F 72 74 0C 6E onPort.n
65 77 54 69 6D 65 73 74 ewTimest
61 6D 70 0E 6E 65 77 4D amp.newM
65 73 73 61 67 65 42 6F essageBo
64 79 01 01 01 01 01 01 dy......
01 00 01 0D 02 00 00 00 ........
06 03 00 00 00 03 44 46 ......DF
58 06 04 00 00 00 01 30 X......0
06 05 00 00 00 0C 30 30 ......00
30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 00000000
30 30 06 06 00 00 00 07 00......
30 2E 30 2E 30 2E 30 06 0.0.0.0.
07 00 00 00 01 30 06 08 .....0..
00 00 00 0B 31 39 32 2E ....192.
31 36 38 2E 31 2E 31 06 168.1.1.
09 00 00 00 04 35 30 30 .....500
30 20 46 FE 12 F9 32 CF 0 Fþ.ù2Ï
88 06 0A 00 00 00 49 70 .....Ip
2C 31 2C 31 32 33 34 35 ,1,12345
36 37 38 39 30 31 32 33 67890123
34 35 36 37 38 39 2C 31 456789,1
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 23456789
30 31 32 33 34 35 2C 31 012345,1
2C 69 6E 74 65 72 6E 65 ,interne
74 2C 75 73 65 72 6E 61 t,userna
6D 65 2C 70 61 73 73 77 me,passw
6F 72 64 2C 30 2C 33 30 ord,0,30
0B                      .
```

When I pick up the message from another solution/project within the app, it fails to parse the message even though it has an identical copy of clsTMessage it's in namespace TelemanusListener.clsTMessage.

Given that it's generically a bad idea to have multiple copies of the class in different parts of the app anyway, what's the reccomended way to do this ?  I've read what MSDN has to say bout this, but it's very thin on how to actually implement it.

Hope I've explained that well enought, if not please ask for more info.

Duncan

Comment: OK, I think I got this now.

Bit of a rookie error really,  I spun out the class into a class library and added a reference to this .dll from each of the elements of the app that needs to access the members of the TMessage class.

I guess that's what class libraries are for really ;-)

Further comments appreciated, but otherwise this might help someone else going down this road.

Duncan

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One class library with a public message type needs to be referenced from the two projects.

Bit of warning about automatic properties - don't use them within classes that need to be serialised/deserialised. Each time a class type is compiled into an assembly, the compiler creates a randomly named backing field for each automatic property. This can cause serialisation problems when you deploy the one/same class library compiled at different times with different projects.